# Update mode in activity, Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to make a menu button in an activity, that lets the user update the content. After clicking it the second time, it should leave the updating mode.

What happens in my program is that with updating mode off I still hear "the sound" while clicking the diagnosticCodeView (I think it's because the onClick method is still overridden). Is there a way to get rid of this sound?

```
    TextView diagnosticCodeView;
    AlertDialog dialog;
    EditText editText;

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.updateReport:
                if(!isEditing) {
                    Snackbar.make(diagnosticCodeView, "Editing mode on", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();

                    diagnosticCodeView = findViewById(R.id.diagnosticCodeView);
                    dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                    editText = new EditText(this);

                    dialog.setTitle(" Edit text ");
                    dialog.setView(editText);

                    dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Save text", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            diagnosticCodeView.setText(editText.getText());
                        }
                    });

                    diagnosticCodeView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            editText.setText(diagnosticCodeView.getText());
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                    });

                    isEditing = true;
                }
                else {
                    Snackbar.make(diagnosticCodeView, "Editing mode off", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();

                    isEditing = false;
                }
                return true;

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to set the listener to null:

```
else {
    Snackbar.make(diagnosticCodeView, "Editing mode off", 
    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();

    diagnosticCodeView.setOnClickListener(null);
    isEditing = false;
}
```